# Should we have a tag for concentration

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I just stumbled acros the [molar](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molar) tag, which does not have a wiki entry. We do not have a tag for molal and I also think this is quite specific. However, we do not have a tag 'concentration', which would cover both if not more. I would suggest this tag with synonyms to the mentioned. Any opinions?

Comment: This makes sense to me.